# Unit Test for Singleton Pattern?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, singleton, moq, system.reflection

Suppose, I am using a package p1 with classes A and B. I do not have access to the implementation of package p1.

Now, in my application I want only one instance of A at any time.

I have created a singleton class C in my application for class A.

Sample:

```
public Class ClassC
{
    private static readonly ClassA singletonObj = new ClassA();

    private ClassC();

    public static ClassA ClassC
    {
       get
       {
          return singletonObj;
       }
    }
}
```

How to unit test on class C to ensure a single instance was created for my application?

Comment: Did you mix up C and A? This is not even a Singleton. Nothing keeps me from calling `new ClassA();` somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't have access to class A and yet I need to impose the single instance of A constraint. SO, I do that through C, but how can I test C. I've seen some examples of IOC and reflection, but I couldn't understand those clearly.

Comment: You cannot impose that constraint without having authority over ClassA. You cannot make any class a Singleton from the outside.

Comment: I understand that, but it's just a specific requirement. How would I test class C above. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? This class is not a Singleton, if your requirement is to absolutely guarantee that only one instance of classA lives inside your program, you will have to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want class A to be singleton, then your above code is irrelevent.
You should write class A like that:

```
public Class ClassA
{
   private static Singleton instance;

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }


//Any other function & members related to ClassA

}
```

In Order to test the singletone, try to create few ClassA instances in your code. Good result is when on every creation of "new instance", you get the same instance, meaning - you can have 2 instances having duffrent data - they will all be kinda pointer to same instance.

Comment: `"try to create few ClassA instances in your code"` How to create new instance when constructor is declared private ? @Inbali Did you mean calling ClassA.Instance multiple times ?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't have access to class A and yet I need to impose the single instance of A constraint. SO, I do that through C, but how can I test C. I've seen some examples of IOC and reflection, but I couldn't understand those clearly.

Comment: I don't understand....If you don't have access to class A then how does it a member of classC? or you don't have access to code of classA?
If you don't have access to classA' code then you can't make this class a singleton.Perhaps you should try use a const bool,outside of any class/shareable in all your project classes, that will indicate if first instance of ClassA were made. On every time in your program when you try create new instance, inside the constuctor check this flag & you'll know if create new classA & chnageflage to false or return the pointer to peviously created instance.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing something similar!